# Unicode meta tag not working as expected

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8

On my local server everything works as expected, but on my company server using 
the **meta charset="utf-8"** tag on my php webpage breaks the correct displaying of special characters. Ommiting it makes the characters display the right way.

The killer in here is that this only occurs on my current php project. If I upload the **getskeleton.com** example however, it displays correctly, and has the **meta charset="utf-8"**.

Any hint why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems some rogue file with western encoding found it's way into my php files. Changed to UTF-8 and it is ok now.

This was really dumb from my part to check such a simple thing, hope this helps others!

If I haven't sort this out my next step would be calling a priest to exorcize the damn thing.

Answer (score 0):

The actual character encoding is not UTF-8, and presumably browsers infer another encoding, which happens to coincide with (or be compatible with) the actual encoding.

For further information on the problem, you need to disclose the actual problem. A URL might help, and so would a description of what “breaks” means (that is, how are some characters displayed?).

Comment: Ok it seems some rogue file with western encoding found it's way into my php files. Changed to UTF-8 and it is ok now.

This was really dumb from my part to check such a simple thing, hope this helps others!

If I haven't sort this out my next step would be calling a priest to exorcize the damn thing.